# OpenXml function in stored procedure won't insert values in given order to table

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, insert

I'm trying to insert a list of X,Y coordinates into a `RideOfferCoordinates` table but the stored procedure function inserts them always in the same order, regardless of the order they are sent in.

I send the coordinates as an xml string:

```
< Coordinates>
< row X="34.9116" Y="32.30498"/>
< row X="34.91151" Y="32.305420000000005"/>
< row X="34.85826" Y="32.328250000000004"/>
< row X="34.855790000000006" Y="32.32117"/>
< /Coordinates>
```

to this sp function:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.SaveRideOfferCoordinates
    (
    @rideOfferId Int,
    @coordinatesXml ntext
    )
AS

declare @idoc int;

exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc out, @coordinatesXml


SELECT X,Y

into #temp

from openxml(@idoc, '/Coordinates/row',1) 

  with (

         X real,

         Y real

       )



insert into RideOfferCoordinates select @rideOfferId, X, Y from #temp

drop table #temp

RETURN 0
```

this should insert `X="34.9116"` `Y="32.30498"` first into the table, but instead it first inserts `X="34.855790000000006"` `Y="32.32117"`, and `X="34.9116"` `Y="32.30498"` last.

My only guess is that sp inserts them in an ascending fashion according to the X values for some reason..

Comment: The coordinates represent a route while the first one in is the origin and the last one is the destination. However, now that i think about it you're right, it really is kinda risky. I'll try your solution. Thanks:)

Comment: Which version of Sql Server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need them in a certain order? Do you need to retrieve them at some point in a certain order? How can you guarantee that?

If you need "order", then add a "Ordinal" column to the table and to the incoming data.

I think you need a "guarantee", rather than a "I sure hope so".

EDIT_-----

If you're using Sql Server 2005 or above........you should abandon OPENXML.

```
-- Declare XML variable

DECLARE @data XML;

-- Element-centered XML

SET @data = N'

<Coordinates>
<row X="34.9116" Y="32.30498" Ordinal="1" />
<row X="34.91151" Y="32.305420000000005" Ordinal="2" />
<row X="34.85826" Y="32.328250000000004" Ordinal="3" />
<row X="34.855790000000006" Y="32.32117" Ordinal="4" />
</Coordinates>

';




SELECT  
        T.childEntity.value('(@X)[1]', 'decimal(16,7)') AS XCoordinate
        ,       T.childEntity.value('(@Y)[1]', 'decimal(16,7)') AS YCoordinate
        ,       T.childEntity.value('(@Ordinal)[1]', 'int') AS MyOrdinal
FROM @data.nodes('Coordinates/row') AS T(childEntity)
```

Comment: Thank you!! you've been a big help. and sorry about the delay