# Best practice for saving application-level data to database (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ajax, state

We have a very large HTML form (> 100 fields) that updates a SQL Server database with user-entered data. It will take the user a long time to fill out the form, but every piece of information they submit is very valuable to the business process. Even if the user gives up on the form, we want to retain everything they have entered.

We plan to attach an onblur event to each field and use jQuery/AJAX to post each piece of data back to the application server immediately. That part is pretty straightforward. The question we have is when and how to best save this application-level information to the database. Again, our priority is data retention as opposed to performance but we also want to do this as efficiently as possible.

Options as I see it are:

1. Have the web service immediately post each piece of data to the database server.
2. Store the information in a custom class on the application server, then periodically call an update method to post new data to the database.
3. Store the information in view or session state, then run a routine to post this information to the database server.
4. Something else that we haven't thought of.

Option 1 seems the most obviously failsafe, but also the most resource intensive. Option 2 seems the most elegant, but can we be absolutely certain that the custom class instance can't be destroyed without first running its update method?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, I'd really cut up the form into sections (if possible). Since this is ASP.Net, if you are using `Web Forms` then look into using `wizards` (cut up the form into logical `Steps`)

You can do same without Form Wizard, but still cut up the process into logical steps, client-side. You can probably do this in pure JavaScript, but it would likely be easier if you used a framework (jQuery, Knockout, etc.) - the concept remains the same, cut up the form entry process into sections (aka 'Steps') - e.g. using display toggles, divs for each "step", etc.

- "retain everything even if abandoned later": assumed that the steps are "hierarchical" where the "most critical" inputs are at the beginning. This makes the "steps" approach even more important - this is a "logical group" (of inputs you really want) so if you do the Step approach, then you can save this data (of this "step") to DB in whatever fashion you deem appropriate (e.g. Ajax, or ASP.Net Post/postback).

Hth...

Comment: Thank you for the response. You are absolutely right: we need to break this up into steps to make it more manageable for the user. We'll probably accomplish this through a jQuery accordion or some other multi-step process. It still doesn't quite get at the heart of our question, which is when to flush this input to the database. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

I would package everything up in some xml or dataset (.getxml) and pass the xml to a stored procedure....

[How to pass XML from C# to a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600091/how-to-pass-xml-from-c-sharp-to-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2008)

And maybe put the call on a background thread.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETBackgroundWorker-dda8d7b6

The xml will be faster than calling the values row by row (RBAR).
You can save just the xml, or shred the xml into a relational table(s).

Comment: Here's an example of shredding xml.......   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778983/openxml-function-in-stored-procedure-wont-insert-values-in-given-order-to-table/16792587#16792587